# set values in web.config dynamically?

Tags: c#, asp.net

in my web.config I have things like:

```
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Entities1" connectionString="metadata=res://*/CData.csdl|res://*/CData.ssdl|res://*/CData.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=ser;initial catalog=dda;persist security info=True;user id=s;password=a;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <add name="Entities2" connectionString="metadata=res://*/M.AuthModel.csdl|res://*/M.AuthModel.ssdl|res://*/M.AuthModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=ser;initial catalog=dda;persist security info=True;user id=s;password=a;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

where I have things like the DB password and so on.

Every time I create a setting in my Project, I get s.th. like:

```
<setting name="db_username" serializeAs="String">
        <value>s</value>
</setting>
```

is it possible to user this `setting` in the `connectionString` above so that I can change e.g. the Username for both with just changing the `setting`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to update the web.config but you could have a method which fetches the connection string.

This method could then get the connection string from the web.config file, fetch the project setting (in this case username) and put it into the connection string before returning it.

Would this be a suitable alternative?

Answer (score 0):

In connection string instead of using username as such you can use some variable like ##username##. Then from code take this connection sring and also the user name from the settings file, and replace ##username## with the setting file username.

Use this connection string to connect. Is that you want?